# Frame Animation in iPad

Tags: iphone, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I wana create an animation like a movie in iPad. I have 1500 frames each frame has 640*480 width n height. I am confused about whats the best way to do it without any memory/performance issue.

I don't wana do it in openGL, more interested in Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

One frame of 640x480 pixels will be 640x480x4 bytes = 1200 kilobytes. You have 1500 frames, so times 1500 = 1.7 gigabytes. That obviously will not fit in memory.

The alternative, if each frame differs only slightly from the previous one, is to store the differences between the frames. I'm not aware of any existing libraries for this. I would like to have something like that myself. ;-)

If the differences between the frames are big, then you're better off encoding it as an actual movie (MP4) and playing that back. Unfortunately, that means you have to deal with the horrible MPMoviePlayerController or going a little more low-level using AV Foundation.

Comment: Thx for your reply dude, I tried MPMOviePlayerController but the issue is if you have 3 different movies and you need to change it on some triggering point, it gives a jerk that is rubbish. Actually I need to play three different movies and if you tap it, it moves to next one without any jerk/flash. I can use AVQueuePlayer but it is only available in iOS 4.0 later. I wana do it in simple way, not in a mood to apply any complex logic in it :)